# How to call function from a third-party library dynamically loaded in React

Tags: reactjs, zendesk-api

We're testing out the ZenDesk web widget, and I have some code that dynamically imports the scripts based on environment, with the following code in the base html file.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    if (window.location.host === 'localhost') {
      var src = "https://static.zdassets.com/ekr/snippet.js?key=<our key>";
      var newScript = document.createElement("script");
      newScript.type = "text/javascript";
      newScript.id = "ze-snippet";
      newScript.setAttribute("async", "true");
      newScript.setAttribute("src", src);
      document.body.appendChild(newScript);
    }
  </script>
```

The help function is dynamic based on URL, but being an SPA, I need to manually call the update function each time the URL changes. How do I go about accessing a function within a third-party library that's being loaded dynamically?

The function that needs to be called on route change is as follows:

```
 zE('webWidget', 'helpCenter:setSuggestions', {
     url: true
 });
```

My app obviously has no idea what zE is, so that won't work. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: your zendesk stuff is probably available in the window domain, try to console.log(window) and see if it's there. Having said that, the better way to do his is not to try and embed scripts like this which directly manipulate the dom inside react. I would try looking for a more node friendly way to interact with zendesk, like https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-zendesk

Comment: I came across that control and for some dumb reason decided to avoid using it, but you were correct. That was extremely easy to set up. Thanks